# When designing an STL style container is it better to use a pass-by-value or pass-by-reference assignment operator?

Tags: c++, stl, assignment-operator

The following is a minimal example of a STL-style container that I have been coding.

**`dynamic_matrix`**

```
template<class _Ty,
    class _Alloc = std::allocator<_Ty>
> class dynamic_matrix {
public:
    // PUBLIC TYPEDEFS
    typedef _Ty value_type;
    typedef _Alloc allocator_type;
    typedef _Ty& reference;
    typedef const _Ty& const_reference;
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    //... other necessary typedefs...
    // CONSTRUCTION/ASSIGNMENT
    dynamic_matrix() : dynamic_matrix(_Alloc()) {}
    explicit dynamic_matrix(const _Alloc& alloc)
        : mtx(alloc), row_(0), cols_(0) {}
    explicit dynamic_matrix(size_type rows, size_type cols, const _Alloc& alloc = _Alloc())
        : mtx(rows*cols, alloc), rows_(rows), cols_(cols) {}
    dynamic_matrix& operator=(dynamic_matrix _other) {
        if (this != &_other)
            swap(*this, _other);
        return *this;
    }
    // ...
    // MODIFIERS
    void swap(dynamic_matrix& _other) {
        mtx.swap(_other.mtx);
        std::swap(rows_, _other.rows_);
        std::swap(cols_, _other.cols_);
    }
    static void swap(dynamic_matrix& lhs, dynamic_matrix& rhs) {
        lhs.swap(rhs);
    }
private:
    std::vector<value_type, allocator_type> mtx;
    size_type rows_;
    size_type cols_;
};
```

As you can see above I am using a single `operator=` which passes `dynamic_matrix` by value allowing the compiler to use copy or move assignment and apply the relevant optimisations.

However, when I look at the assignment operators in the interfaces of typical STL containers (e.g. [`std::vector::operator=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D) and [`std::deque::operator=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/operator%3D)) they have two overloaded versions - one for move and one for copy where the latter uses pass by `const reference` rather than pass-by-value.

So, when creating the assignment operator(s) for `dynamic_matrix` should I instead use the below version to be in keeping with the STL style or stick to pass-by-value which is better?

(Alternative `dynamic_matrix::operator=`):

```
// copy-assign
dynamic_matrix& operator=(const dynamic_matrix& _other) {
    if (this != &_other)
        dynamic_matrix(_other).swap(*this);
    return *this;
}  
// move-assign
dynamic_matrix& operator=(dynamic_matrix&& _other) {
    if (this != &_other)
        swap(*this, _other);
    return *this;
}
```

---

*Note: I'm aware the STL interface is not the be-all and end-all of container design, but if I'm creating a container which is as close to STL design as I can make then sticking to the standard might be more suitable.*

Comment: `_Ty` and `_Alloc` are implementation reserved names, don't use them in user code.

Comment: Just a note: If you are passing by value, it is impossible for the this pointer to be the same as the arguments address.

Comment: Wait? Why would you want to copy and move instead of only copying? Moving might be cheaper than copying, though it ain't free.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Oops, didn't realise that, hadn't come across problems with it before but I'll avoid it now.

Comment: @JVApen  This allows both with one operator, the by value argument will be move constructed if possible.

Comment: @nate Yeah I just realised that, that's easily fixed.

Comment: I've seen this discussed several times lately, and it seems much easier to write, with no downside.

Comment: @juanchopanza the argument is moved into parameter which is then swapped with the class instance. So the parameter becomes a temporary that prevents the this pointer from matching.

Comment: You might be interested in the [article](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.ca/2014/06/the-drawbacks-of-implementing-move.html) by Scott Meyers on a couple drawbacks with the copy-swap idiom. It's good to keep everything in mind when faced with the decision.

Comment: @nate That is assuming copy and swap is used (or a copy of the argument is required.) But that is not necessarily the best way to implement assignment, in which case passing by value incurs one extra copy when the RHS is an lvalue.

Comment: @juanchopanza I agree, if you don't plan on implementing move as a strait swap, then this shortcut is bad.

Comment: Copy-and-swap is good for getting something up and running, because you only need to think about your copy-/move-constructors to get things right (swap is trivial). It is not necessarily the best way of performing assignment, though. In fact, it's pretty much guaranteed to be slower than a destructive update. Pick it because you want something that works, not something that's optimized.

Comment: If you pass an lvalue to `std::vector::operator=` it will reuse any existing capacity in the vector. Your assignment operator will always allocate a new container (see [this talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnqTKD8uD64&t=51m5s) by Herb Sutter).